# Perimeter of non simply connected binary images

Tags: c++, image-processing, geometry

I´m trying to compute the perimeter of a region in binary images. When a region is simply connected, i.e. it has no "holes", everything is quite simple: I just check for every pixel if it belongs to the region and has at least a neighbor which is not belonging to the region... I have a variable that counts the number of pixels satisfying this condition.

In the case of region with holes I use a different way. I start from a pixel in the border and "jump" to a neighbor (increasing a counter) if it is itself a border pixel. The procedure, with some more quirks, ends when I go back to the initial pixels. Something like this:

```
int iPosCol = iStartCol, int iPosRow = iStartRow;
do 
{
  //check neighbors, pick point on the perimeter
  //condition: value == label, pixel at the border.
  check8Neighbors(iPosCol, iPosRow);
  updatePixPosition(iPosCol, iPosRow);
}
while ( iPosC != iStartC || iPosR != iStartR );
```

The problem is that this method won´t work if the holes in the region are close to the border (1-pixel distance).

Are there standard ways of computing perimeter of non simply connected regions, or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean by perimeter here? Is it the number of same-colored pixels in the region? Or is it the area bounded by the regions borders?

Comment: The images are binary, so white regions and black background. Perimeter is defined as the number of pixels on the border of a region.

Comment: Ok, then one last question - how do you define the border of a region(especially one with a hole)

Comment: For region with no holes: all the points belonging to the region with at least one neighbor pixel non-belonging to the region

Comment: Region with holes: here´s where it´s difficult, because I can only intuitively distinguish between border/non border pixels, but can´t find a proper mathematical definition...

Comment: My point was - do you consider the border of the holes to be part of the border?

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understand, sorry. No, they shouldn´t be considered part of the border.

Comment: Writing a contour-following algorithm that can deal with all possible contour geometries is a little tricky, but the paper by Chang and Chen that I mention in my response covers the important cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my proposition: 
Let's assume you want to find the border of a black region(for simplicity).
First add one extra white column and one extra white row on all sides of the image. This is done to simplify corner cases and I will try to explain where it helps.

Next do a breadth first search from any pixel in your region. The edges in the graph are defined as connecting neighbouring cells in black color. By doing this BFS you will find all the pixels in your region. Now select the bottom-most(you can find it linerly) and if there are many bottom-most just select any of them. Select the pixel that is below it - this pixel is white for sure because: we selected the bottom-most of the pixels in our region and if the pixel was black the BFS would have visited it. Also there is a pixel below our bottom-most pixel because of the extra rows and columns we added.

Now do another BFS this time passing through white nighbouring pixels(again the fact that we added additional rows and columns helps here). This way we find a white region that surrounds the black region we are interested in from everywhere. Now all the pixels from the original black region that are neighbouring *any* of the pixels in the newly found white region are part of the border and only they are part of it. So you count those pixels and there you go - you have the perimeter.

The solution is complicated by the fact that we do not want to count borders of the holes as part of the perimeter - had this condition not be present we could just count all the pixels in the initial black region that are neighbouring any white pixel or the border of the image(here we do not need to add rows and colums).

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment, istrandjev. I´m trying it right now, will see if it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

As JCooper noted, connected component a.k.a. region labeling a.k.a. contour detection is an algorithm to find regions of connected pixels, typically in an image that has been binarized so that all pixels are black or white.

The Wikipedia entry for **Connected-component labeling** includes pseudocode for a "single pass" algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Another single-pass algorithm can be found in the paper "A Component-Labeling Algorithm Using Contour Tracing Technique" by Chang and Chen. This paper also includes a description of an edge-following algorithm you can use to find just the contour, if you'd like. 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.58.3213

That paper describes edge-following well enough, but I'll describe the basic idea here.

Let's say the outer contour of a figure is represented by pixels a through f, and background pixels are represented by "-":

```
- - - - -
- a b - -
- - - c -
- - - d -
- f e - -
- - - - -
```

If we're scanning the image from top to bottom, and along each row from left to right, then the first pixel encountered is pixel a. To move from pixel a to pixel b, and then from b to c, we track the direction of each move using 8 directions defined relative to the current pixel, p:

```
6 7 8
5 p 1
4 3 2
```

The move from the background "-" to pixel "a" is along direction 1. Although we know where "b" is, the software doesn't, so we check all directions clockwise about "a" to find the next pixel along the contour. We don't need to check direction 5 (left) because we just came from the background pixel to the left of "a." What we do is check directions clockwise 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, etc., looking for the next contour pixel. We find "b" also along direction 1 after finding only background pixels in directions 6, 7, and 8 relative to "a."

If we look at the transition from c to d, we move in direction 3. To find the next contour pixel "e," we check directions 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, and we find contour pixel "e" by moving in direction 4.

The general rule is that if our last move was in direction d, the first direction we check for our next move is direction d - 3. If the last move was in direction 5 (moving left), then we start our next clockwise search at direction 2.

In code we would usually use directions 0 - 7, and clearly you'll make use of the modulo operation or similar math, but I hope the idea is clear. The Chang and Chen paper describes the basic contour-following algorithm reasonably well, and also mentions necessary checks if the algorithm needs to retrace certain pixels.

---

An edge-following algorithm may be sufficient for your needs, but for a variety of reasons you might want to find connection regions of pixels, too.

For a connected component algorithm, one thing to keep in mind is what you want to consider a "neighbor" of a pixel. You can look at just the "4-neighbors":

```
-  n  -
n  p  n
-  n  -
```

where "p" is the center pixel, "n" marks four neighbors, and "-" marks pixels that are not considered neighbors. You can also consider the "8-neighbors," which are simply all pixels surrounding a given pixel:

```
n  n  n
n  p  n
n  n  n
```

Typically, 4-neighbors are the better choice when checking connectivity for foreground objects. If you select an 8-neighbor technique, then a checkerboard pattern like the following could be considered a single object:

```
p - p - p - p - p
- p - p - p - p - 
p - p - p - p - p
- p - p - p - p - 
p - p - p - p - p
- p - p - p - p -
```

Let's say you have a blob that looks like the one below, with foreground pixels labeled as "p" and background pixels labeled as "-":

```
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - p p p - - -
- - p p p - p p - -
- - - p p - p p - -
- - - - p p p - - -
- p p p p p p - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
```

If you consider just the pixels of the outer contour, you'll see that it can be a little tricky calculating the perimeter. For the pixels 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 below, you can calculate the perimeter using the pixels 1 - 5, moving in stepwise fashion from pixel 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, etc. Typically it's better to calculate the perimeter for this segment using only pixels 1, 3, and 5 along the diagonal. For the single row of pixels at bottom, you must be careful that the algorithm does not count those pixels twice.

```
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - - p p p - - -
- - 1 2 p - p p - -
- - - 3 4 - p p - -
- - - - 5 p p - - -
- p p p p p p - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
```

For relatively large connected regions without "peninsulas" jutting out that are a single pixel wide, calculating the perimeter is relatively straightforward. For very small objects it's hard to calculate the "true" perimeter in part because we have a limited number of discrete, square pixels representing a real-world object with a contour that is likely smooth and slightly curvy. The image representation of the object is chunky.

If you have an ordered list of the pixels found from an edge tracing algorithm, then you can calculate the perimeter by checking the change in X and the change in Y of two successive pixels in the list of contour pixels. You calculate the perimeter by calculating the sum of pixel-to-pixel distances along contour pixels.

For pixel N and pixel N + 1: if either X is the same or Y is the same then the direction from N to N + 1 is left, right, up, or down, and the distance is 1.

If both X and Y are different for pixels N and N + 1, then the direction moving from one pixel to the next is at a 45-degree angle to the horizontal, and the distance between pixel centers is the square root of 2.

Whatever algorithm you create, consider checking its accuracy against simple figures: a square, a rectangle, a circle, etc. A circle is particular helpful to check perimeter calculation because the contour of a circle (esp. a small circle) in an image will have jagged rather than smooth edges.

```
- - - - - - - - - -
- - - p p p p - - -
- - p p p p p p - -
- - p p p p p p - -
- - p p p p p p - -
- - - p p p p - - -
- - - - - - - - - -
```

There are techniques to find shapes and calculate perimeters in grayscale and color images that don't rely on binarization to make the image just black and white, but those techniques are trickier. For many applications the simple, standard technique will work:

1. Choose a threshold to binarize the image.
2. Run a connected component / region labeling algorithm on the binarized image
3. Use the contour pixels of a connected region to calculate perimeter

An image processing textbook used in many universities has the answer to many of your questions about image processing. If you're going to delve into image processing, you should have at least one textbook like this one handy; it'll save you hours of hunting online for answers.

**Digital Image Processing** (3rd edition) by Gonzalez and Woods

Book website:
http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/

You should be able to find an international edition for about $35 online.

If you end up writing a lot of code to perform geometric calculations, another handy reference book is **Geometric Tools for Computer Graphics** by Schneider and Eberly.

[http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Computer-Graphics-Morgan-Kaufmann/dp/1558605940](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605940)

It's pricey, but you can find used copies cheap sometimes at multi-site search engines like

http://www.addall.com

Corrections, PDFs of theory, and code from the book can be found here:
http://www.geometrictools.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest thing to do would be to run a connected component algorithm and then fill in the holes.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you mean? I fail to see how can I get only the border pixels in this case